# remove white space in RDLC POS receipt

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I’m using C# windows form
I have an issue in RDLC that the printed PDF always has empty space in the end of the report .
What I did to fix the issue :

1. Interactive size =0 (width and height )
2. ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace =true
3. Check the PageBreakAtEnd and PageBreakAtStart != true

Important note that the height is unknown as it’s used in POS printer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5jn3.png)

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you could you explain more if you please

Comment: What exactly do you mean `empty space in the end of the report`? This may have to do with your page size and footers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to show or hide any of the objects.

> =IIf(IsNothing(Fields!YourData.Value), True, False)

If you are using Table/Tablix you have to set the Visibility property of your TABLEROW

Comment: unfortunately I don't have any hidden field in Tablix